# EmEditor snippet plugin no longer remembers which snippet collections were open (20.9)

Tags: code-snippets, emeditor

After upgrading from EmEditor 20.8.1 to 20.9, closing the snippets panel now collapses all open snippets collections, even though the plugin has been set to keep running in the background. I have to manually reopen the collections after activating the snippets panel.

Is this change of behavior intentional? Am I overlooking something?

Comment: For bug reports, please email tech @ emurasoft.com.

Comment: Done. Feel free to delete this question.